# FlatList only showing data of one REST API in react native

Tags: reactjs, rest, api, react-native, axios

I'm trying to consume a REST API and insert the data into a FlatList. I tested my code with an example API but now that I want to use my own API it doesn't show any data.

I have my api tested in other screens of my app and it works perfect, but suddenly in the FlatList is not.

```
makeRemoteRequest = () => {
        const url = `https://randomuser.me/api/?&results=20`;
        this.setState({ loading: true });

        fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    data: res.results,
                    error: res.error || null,
                    loading: false,
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({ error, loading: false });
            });
    };


<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <ListItem
                            title={item.name.first}
                            subtitle={item.email}
                        />
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.email}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
                    ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
                />
            </View>
```

I have changed the url with my own url and the fields in the  but it shows an empty list.

It's working but not showing the data, only when I write my own url.

I hope you can help me, I can't see nothing bad in the code.

Comment: Before looking into great detail, a simple question. Have you console logged `res` before your `setState`?

Comment: Check your View first. Is it work well? 
And where you call `makeRemoteRequest()` ?

Comment: @AdamRoberts I have console logged res using both api and only works with the example api "https://randomuser.me/api/?&results=20" but when I use my own api it doesn't work. I have other request to my own api in other screen and it works perfectly.

Comment: @JeffGuKang I call the function in componentDidMount()

Comment: So it seems something within that request is causing issues with your API. Have you checked your network tab in developer tools? Is the request being made to your API? What is the response?

Comment: Just to confirm, I've added in a simple fetch as you've done above and it works fine, so it appears to be something in your implementation

Comment: @AdamRoberts [link] (https://github.com/vikrantnegi/react-native-searchable-flatlist/blob/master/src/SearchableList.js)  Here is the implementation, the only thing I am changing is the url and the item fields. I'm still don't know what's wrong. My api is [link] (https://goaccesoremoto.herokuapp.com/api/invitados/)

Comment: Honestly I can't see much wrong with this. There are improvements that could be made to the code itself (we can cover that later) but I've pulled the rest into a project (minus the components as i'm using react, not native) and i receive a response. Are you seeing console logs in the console at all? What do you see in the console when looking at the request itself?

Comment: Try adding key={index} prop in your <ListItem>

Comment: It will be better to show your full code.

Comment: The Flatlist and components are not the issue if you're getting nothing when console logging the response. As i mentioned above, do you see anything in your network tab?

Comment: @AdamRoberts I get the JSON Object when I console log the response. The HTTP request is being made.